# WPF: Investigate WPF app crash by unhandled exceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, asynchronous

I'm handling all unhandled exceptions in my WPF app using `App.DispatcherUnhandledException += Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)` and also all my async void methods are decorated by try-catch block, but my app still sometimes crashes and shows dialog "App has stopped working". I cannot replicate this behaviour on my developer machine, so I haven't more details about exception.

After every crash I find these 2 logs in event logger on client computers:

> Application: app.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.IOException Stack: at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__5(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

and

> app.exe  0.21.3.0    557e902a    KERNELBASE.dll 
>     6.3.9600.17415    54504ade    e0434352    00014598    2770    01d0a801cc61d343

Is there any way to find source of this exception or to handle ALL exceptions on the application level?

Comment: `DispatcherUnhandledException` doesn't catch *all* exceptions. See `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks, I have also method attached to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event, but there is no Handled property on UnhandledExceptionEventArgs object, so I can't mark these exceptions as handled...

Comment: You shouldn't mark every unhandled exception as handled.  It's not a good idea.  You should try to make sure that exceptions you can handle get handled (preferably as close to the code that causes them as possible).  Think about what happens when that `IOException` occurs because you couldn't load a (necessary) file - and your app continues on as if it had been loaded, because no exception got thrown or (properly) handled...